# Scrolling in Touchpad doesn't work on Acer Aspire S3

Tags: linux-mint, mouse, touchpad

I'm on the latest Linux Mint release on an *Acer Aspire S3*. Unfortunately I can't scroll using my Touchpad. Google helped a little bit since I now know that there should be Touchpad options in System Settings -> Mouse. Unfortunately this is not true for me.

Could somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: This is fixed by upgrading to Linux Mint 13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to Linux Mint 13 fixes this problem.